# two dollar signs in insert mode in VIM

Tags: vim

When I type two dollar signs $$ in insert mode in VIM it changes the text to $$<++>. What does this mean? And how do I make it no longer do this?

Comment: May be it is an abbreviation? Try `:verbose abbreviate`

Comment: A helpful tool: [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com). With it you can search for things like [`<++>`](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%2B%2B%3E) (and find that latex-suite seems to be related)!

Comment: @Chris Morgan: +1 for this comment, very nice tool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a place holder inserted by the latex-suite plugin. You can  jump to it with `<C-j>` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).

see "Place Holders" section here: http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the latex-suite plugin (or something similar). Use `:scriptnames` to see which plugins have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right, I am typing Latex and when I ask VIM to show the running scripts like you say it gives lots latex-related plug-ins. It is probably one of those; now I expect my problem to be related to folding-plugin

Answer (score 1):

May be an abbreviation or a map. Check

```
:ia
```

or

```
:imap
```

with a result like:

```
i  $$            $$<++>
```

If found there, remove it with:

```
:inuabbrev $$
```

or with

```
:iunmap $$
```

Answer (score 1):

In general hunt for unknown/unwanted mappings with:

```
:verbose map $$
```

or

```
:verbose abbr $$
```

Not only will it tell you what mappings/abbreviations exist, but also ***where***.