# Vim $$ automatically adds <++>

Tags: vim

For some reason, whenever I type `$$` in Vim, it automatically adds `<++>` right after it, and positions my cursor between the `$` symbols.

So I get something this in the end (| indicates cursor position):

```
$|$<++>
```

I am using [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) package, but I am not sure if that has something to do with it.
I am using `$$` a lot for the math environment, so it really gets old fighting vim on this.

Does anyone know what this thing is and how do I disable it (or use it properly)?

EDIT: Just for clarification, I actually want the double dollar sign, to make a multi-line math environement:

```
$$
x+ y
$$
```

Comment: Use CTRL-J to navigate to the next <++>.

Comment: Updated. Sorry, but I meant that I want the double $$ environment... not the inline one

Comment: it's better practice to use `\[xyz\]` instead of `$$xyz$$`, and `\(xyz\)` instead of `$xyz$`

Comment: Wow, thanks, that even made vim's bracket matching work! Amazing.

Comment: exact duplicate of

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574365/two-dollar-signs-in-insert-mode-in-vim/8575030#8575030

Comment: @Niels wow, how long did it take you to find that? I was searching for a similar question, but didn't think to type "two dollar signs"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Benoit wrote, you can use `Ctrl-J` to jump to the next `<++>`. These are called *place holders* and are explained in chapter 3 of the vim-latex documentation: [Latex-Suite Macros](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html).

Comment: Oh I understand, it's for helping with the inline math. But what if I want double $$'s?

Comment: As pointed out by @Benoit, one should use `\[` and `\]` instead of opening and closing `$$` respectively.